# Get the type which a template class consist of

Tags: c++, templates, typeid

Having  -

**C_Type.h**

```
#ifndef C_TYPE_H
#define C_TYPE_H
template <class T>
class C_Type {
    public:
        T m_val;
            // implementation ... 

};

#endif
```

And a program  -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "C_Type.h"
using namespace std ; 


int main () {
    C_Type<int> a  ; 
    cout <<typeid(a.m_val).name()<<endl;

}
```

I trying to extract the `int` which `C_Type<int>` consist of  , the above program just gave output  - `i` .

**Edit  :**

Is it possible to get the type (i.e int or i)  with no regards to the class members (i.e `m_val`) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name returned by [typeid::name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) is compiler specific and for some compiler it is something horrible (like `i` for `int`). Most compilers support demangling of names which leads to a nicer representation, but still is useless for programmatic use.

Here is a list of demangling APIs for common compilers:

- [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html)
- [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks ,  I added one more related question .. your help would be welcome

Comment: It's not usually something horrid.  Most compilers try to do something useful.  g++ seems to be the only exception here.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, I think I was exaggerating. I made the sentence a little milder.

Comment: Yes.  The "but still useless for programmatic use" pretty much sums it up.

Answer (score 3):

In response to your last question (concerning getting the type
without referring to a member): no.  In the standard library,
there is a convention to provide `typedef` for the
instantiation type and the types derived from it; the usual name
is `value_type`, but there are exceptions (e.g. `std::map`).  If
you want to adhere to this convention (which isn't a bad idea),
you should add:

```
typedef T value_type;
```

to your class (as a public member), and refer to it when you
want the type, rather than some arbitrary member (which may or
may not be present).

Answer (score 1):

"i" is the correct name may be of the type "int"?
it's just a name! What do you want to do with the name?

```
 int main () {
    C_Type<int> a  ; 
    int test=0;
    if(typeid(a.m_val) == typeid(test))
      cout <<"Int"<<endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve the template parameter from a template specification (and you have C++11), you can do this:

```
template <template <typename> class Templ, typename T>
T typeGetter(Templ<T>);
```

Then, in your main:

```
int main () {
    C_Type<int> a;
    decltype(typeGetter(a)) i = 7; //declares i to be int
}
```